# В чем причина ошибки IntPredicate cannot be resolved to a type Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных, лямбда-выражение

Прошу помочь выполнить пример. Привожу его как есть из книги И.Н. Блинов, В.С. Романчик - JAVA FROM EPAM (2020). VSC выдает ошибку **"IntPredicate cannot be resolved to a type Java(16777218)".**
java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS

```
    int[] arrayInt = {1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65};

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arrayInt)
      .filter(((IntPredicate) i -> i > 32).or(i -> i < 4))
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Непонятно. Работает без ошибок даже в жаба-шеле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примерах обычно пропускают импорты:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayInt = {1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65};

        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arrayInt)
                .filter(((IntPredicate) i -> i > 32).or(i -> i < 4))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, в этот раз VSCode почему то не предложил импорт.